# Error on accessing website DXA 1.4

Tags: dxa, sdl-tridion, dxa-1.4, web8

DXA 1.4 installed successfully on SDL Web 8.1.1 + Topology and published all the pages got success.

Accessed the Website URL: http://dxastaging.sdlweb8.indi/

Getting the output on the website response:

```
No matching Localization found for URL 'http://dxastaging.sdlweb8.indi/'
```

Accessed the website URL: http://dxastaging.sdlweb8.indi/index.html

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> {"error":{"code":"4000","message":"Not possible to marshall single
>   entity stream JSON: "}}
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceClientException:
>   {"error":{"code":"4000","message":"Not possible to marshall single
>   entity stream JSON: "}}
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [DataServiceClientException: {"error":{"code":"4000","message":"Not
>   possible to marshall single entity stream JSON: "}}]
>   Microsoft.OData.Client.QueryResult.ExecuteQuery() +613
>   Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceRequest.Execute(DataServiceContext
>   context, QueryComponents queryComponents) +314
>
> [DataServiceQueryException: An error occurred while processing this
>   request.]
>   Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceRequest.Execute(DataServiceContext
>   context, QueryComponents queryComponents) +874
>   Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceContext.InnerSynchExecute(Uri
>   requestUri, String httpMethod, Nullable`1 singleResult,
>   OperationParameter[] operationParameters) +555
>
>   Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceContext.Execute(Uri requestUri) +117
>   Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.<>c__DisplayClass23.<Execute>b__20() +82
>
>   Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.DummyCacheProvider.AddOrGetExisting(String
>   key, Func`1 addFactory, Boolean useCache) +12
>   Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.<>c__DisplayClass21`1.b__1f() +307
>
> [ServiceQueryException: Failed to execute query]
>   Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.AbstractODataService.HandleHttpResponseCode(Exception
>   e, Int32 statusCode) +162
>   Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.<>c__DisplayClass21`1.<Execute>b__1f() +423
>
>   Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.Utils.PerformRetry(Func`1 block, Int32
>   retryCount) +113    Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.Utils.Retry(Func`1 block,
>   Int32 retryCount, Boolean locking) +239
>   Sdl.Web.Delivery.Dynamic.DynamicMappingsRetrieverImpl.GetPublicationMapping(String
>   url) +265
>   Tridion.ContentDelivery.DynamicContent.DynamicMappingsRetriever.GetPublicationMapping(String
>   url) +68
>   Sdl.Web.Tridion.CdApiLocalizationResolver.ResolveLocalization(Uri url)
>   in c:\Jenkins\workspace\DXA Dev CI Web App
>   .NET\Sdl.Web.Tridion\CdApiLocalizationResolver.cs:66
>   Sdl.Web.Mvc.Configuration.WebRequestContext.get_Localization() in
>   c:\Jenkins\workspace\DXA Dev CI Web App
>   .NET\Sdl.Web.Mvc\Configuration\WebRequestContext.cs:23
>   Sdl.Web.Mvc.Statics.StaticContentModule.BeginRequest(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) in c:\Jenkins\workspace\DXA Dev CI Web App
>   .NET\Sdl.Web.Mvc\Statics\StaticContentModule.cs:97
>   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +92    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +165

**Site.log:**

> 2016-05-06 02:59:57,142 [8] ERROR - Failed to execute query
>   Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.ServiceQueryException: Failed to execute
>   query ---> Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceQueryException: An error
>   occurred while processing this request. --->
>   Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceClientException:
>   {"error":{"code":"4000","message":"Not possible to marshall single
>   entity stream JSON: "}}    at
>   Microsoft.OData.Client.QueryResult.ExecuteQuery()    at
>   Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceRequest.Execute[TElement](DataServiceContext
>   context, QueryComponents queryComponents)    --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace ---    at
>   Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceRequest.Execute[TElement](DataServiceContext
>   context, QueryComponents queryComponents)    at
>   Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceContext.InnerSynchExecute[TElement](Uri
>   requestUri, String httpMethod, Nullable`1 singleResult,
>   OperationParameter[] operationParameters)    at
>   Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceContext.Execute[TElement](Uri
>   requestUri)    at
>   Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.ODataV4Service.<>c__DisplayClass21`1.<>c__DisplayClass23.b__20()
>   at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.DummyCacheProvider.AddOrGetExisting(String
>   key, Func`1 addFactory, Boolean useCache)    at
>   Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.ODataV4Service.<>c__DisplayClass21`1.b__1f()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.AbstractODataService.HandleHttpResponseCode(Exception
>   e, Int32 statusCode)    at
>   Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.ODataV4Service.<>c__DisplayClass21`1.<Execute>b__1f()
>   at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.Utils.PerformRetry[T](Func`1 block, Int32
>   retryCount)    at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.Utils.Retry[T](Func`1
>   block, Int32 retryCount, Boolean locking)    at
>   Sdl.Web.Delivery.Dynamic.DynamicMappingsRetrieverImpl.GetPublicationMapping(String
>   url)    at
>   Tridion.ContentDelivery.DynamicContent.DynamicMappingsRetriever.GetPublicationMapping(String
>   url)    at
>   Sdl.Web.Tridion.CdApiLocalizationResolver.ResolveLocalization(Uri url)
>   in c:\Jenkins\workspace\DXA Dev CI Web App
>   .NET\Sdl.Web.Tridion\CdApiLocalizationResolver.cs:line 66    at
>   Sdl.Web.Mvc.Configuration.WebRequestContext.get_Localization() in
>   c:\Jenkins\workspace\DXA Dev CI Web App
>   .NET\Sdl.Web.Mvc\Configuration\WebRequestContext.cs:line 23    at
>   Sdl.Web.Mvc.Statics.StaticContentModule.BeginRequest(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) in c:\Jenkins\workspace\DXA Dev CI Web App
>   .NET\Sdl.Web.Mvc\Statics\StaticContentModule.cs:line 54

**Error log on ContentServiceCapability (session) cd_core.log:**

> 2016-05-06 02:57:31,507 ERROR JsonWriter - Not possible to marshall
>   single entity stream JSON 2016-05-06 02:57:31,523 ERROR
>   ODataRendererActor - Exception during response rendering -
>   com.sdl.odata.api.renderer.ODataRenderException: 'Not possible to
>   marshall single entity stream JSON: '
>   com.sdl.odata.api.renderer.ODataRenderException: Not possible to
>   marshall single entity stream JSON:   at
>   com.sdl.odata.renderer.json.writer.JsonWriter.writeEntry(JsonWriter.java:130)
>   ~[odata_renderer-2.0.5-1002.jar:2.0.5-1002]   at
>   com.sdl.odata.renderer.json.JsonRenderer.render(JsonRenderer.java:70)
>   ~[odata_renderer-2.0.5-1002.jar:2.0.5-1002]   at
>   com.sdl.odata.service.actor.ODataRendererActor.renderResult(ODataRendererActor.scala:124)
>   [odata_service-2.0.5-1002.jar:2.0.5-1002]     at
>   com.sdl.odata.service.actor.ODataRendererActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(ODataRendererActor.scala:74)
>   ~[odata_service-2.0.5-1002.jar:2.0.5-1002]    at
>   akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:480)
>   [akka-actor_2.11-2.4.1.jar:na]    at
>   com.sdl.odata.service.actor.ODataRendererActor.aroundReceive(ODataRendererActor.scala:33)
>   [odata_service-2.0.5-1002.jar:2.0.5-1002]     at
>   akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:526)
>   [akka-actor_2.11-2.4.1.jar:na]    at
>   akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:495)
>   [akka-actor_2.11-2.4.1.jar:na]    at
>   akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)
>   [akka-actor_2.11-2.4.1.jar:na]    at
>   akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)
>   [akka-actor_2.11-2.4.1.jar:na]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>   [na:1.8.0_92]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>   [na:1.8.0_92]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_92]
>   Caused by: com.sdl.odata.api.renderer.ODataRenderException:
>   Non-nullable property has null value: Port    at
>   com.sdl.odata.renderer.json.writer.JsonWriter.marshallStructuralProperty(JsonWriter.java:316)
>   ~[odata_renderer-2.0.5-1002.jar:2.0.5-1002]   at
>   com.sdl.odata.renderer.json.writer.JsonWriter.lambda$marshallStructured$11(JsonWriter.java:262)
>   ~[odata_renderer-2.0.5-1002.jar:2.0.5-1002]   at
>   com.sdl.odata.util.edm.EntityDataModelUtil.visitProperties(EntityDataModelUtil.java:372)
>   ~[odata_api-2.0.5-1002.jar:2.0.5-1002]    at
>   com.sdl.odata.renderer.json.writer.JsonWriter.marshallStructured(JsonWriter.java:236)
>   ~[odata_renderer-2.0.5-1002.jar:2.0.5-1002]   at
>   com.sdl.odata.renderer.json.writer.JsonWriter.marshall(JsonWriter.java:204)
>   ~[odata_renderer-2.0.5-1002.jar:2.0.5-1002]   at
>   com.sdl.odata.renderer.json.writer.JsonWriter.writeJson(JsonWriter.java:169)
>   ~[odata_renderer-2.0.5-1002.jar:2.0.5-1002]   at
>   com.sdl.odata.renderer.json.writer.JsonWriter.writeEntry(JsonWriter.java:126)
>   ~[odata_renderer-2.0.5-1002.jar:2.0.5-1002]   ... 12 common frames
>   omitted

```
PS C:\Installation\SDL DXA .NET 1.4\cms> Get-TtmWebsite


    BaseUrls             : {http://dxalive.sdlweb8.indi:80}
    CdEnvironmentId      : CdEnvironment2
    EnvironmentPurpose   : Live
    CdEnvironment        :
    ScopedRepositoryKeys : {DxaSiteType, DxaExampleSite}
    Id                   : Website2
    ExtensionProperties  : {}

    BaseUrls             : {http://dxastaging.sdlweb8.indi:80}
    CdEnvironmentId      : CdEnvironment1
    EnvironmentPurpose   : Staging
    CdEnvironment        :
    ScopedRepositoryKeys : {DxaSiteType, DxaExampleSite}
    Id                   : Website1
    ExtensionProperties  : {}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score -1):

Underlying error is indicated as

```
Non-nullable property has null value: Port
```

This generally happens when BaseURL for a website is incorrect (probably issue with port not set). Check if you have configured Website from Topology Manager with correct BaseURL.

Comment: Yes it's configured the same see the updated comments above

Comment: @Velmurugan hi- I am facing same issue/error at my end, can you please suggest how to fix it; thanks

Comment: There seems to be a defect in the Content Service causing this issue if default HTTP(S) ports are used. See http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/16217/getting-error-if-using-port-80-for-website-build-on-sdl-web8-and-dxa-1-6

Comment: You should also consider using different ports for Dev and Staging sites..I believe they are separate Site in IIS.