# DXA 1.5 website throwing error when accessed in distributed Web 8.1 setup

Tags: dxa, web8, dxa-1.5

I am implementing DXA 1.5 with Web 8.1 in a distributed architecture. Already setup CMS and CD on separate servers successfully.

All services microservices are running on the default port as mentioned in SDL Docs.

But I am trying to hit the DXA website URL, it is throwing the below error:-

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> {"error":{"code":"9000","message":"java.lang.NullPointerException:
> null"}}

[image]

All pages and _System folder is already published successfully.

All services are accessible from CMS server as well.

Error in **site.log** error is given below however not getting any error in **cd_client log** of website:-

```
2016-07-21 18:01:16,458 [8] ERROR - Failed to execute query
Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.ServiceQueryException: Failed to execute query ---> Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceQueryException: An error occurred while processing this request. ---> Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceClientException: {"error":{"code":"9000","message":"java.lang.NullPointerException: null"}}
   at Microsoft.OData.Client.QueryResult.ExecuteQuery()
   at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceRequest.Execute[TElement](DataServiceContext context, QueryComponents queryComponents)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceRequest.Execute[TElement](DataServiceContext context, QueryComponents queryComponents)
   at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceContext.InnerSynchExecute[TElement](Uri requestUri, String httpMethod, Nullable`1 singleResult, OperationParameter[] operationParameters)
   at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceContext.Execute[TElement](Uri requestUri)
   at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.ODataV4Service.<>c__DisplayClass19_1`1.<Execute>b__1()
   at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.MemoryCacheProvider.AddOrGetExisting(String key, Func`1 addFactory, Boolean useCache)
   at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.ODataV4Service.<>c__DisplayClass19_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.AbstractODataService.HandleHttpResponseCode(Exception e, Int32 statusCode)
   at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.ODataV4Service.<>c__DisplayClass19_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.Utils.PerformRetry[T](Func`1 block, Int32 retryCount)
   at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.Utils.Retry[T](Func`1 block, Int32 retryCount, Boolean locking)
   at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Dynamic.DynamicMappingsRetrieverImpl.GetPublicationMapping(String url)
   at Tridion.ContentDelivery.DynamicContent.DynamicMappingsRetriever.GetPublicationMapping(String url)
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.CdApiLocalizationResolver.ResolveLocalization(Uri url) in c:\Jenkins\workspace\DXA Dev CI Web App .NET\Sdl.Web.Tridion\CdApiLocalizationResolver.cs:line 66
   at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Configuration.WebRequestContext.get_Localization() in c:\Jenkins\workspace\DXA Dev CI Web App .NET\Sdl.Web.Mvc\Configuration\WebRequestContext.cs:line 23
   at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Statics.StaticContentModule.BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Jenkins\workspace\DXA Dev CI Web App .NET\Sdl.Web.Mvc\Statics\StaticContentModule.cs:line 51
```

Also getting some error in **cd_core.log** file of session microservice as given below:-

```
2016-07-21 18:01:16,440 ERROR ODataRendererActor - Unexpected exception during response rendering - java.lang.NullPointerException: 'null'
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.ehcache.jcache.JCache.put(JCache.java:228) ~[jcache-1.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.sdl.web.discovery.delivery.configuration.CachingConfigurationProvider.provide(CachingConfigurationProvider.java:91) ~[discovery-client-8.1.1-1009.jar:8.1.1-1009]
    at com.sdl.delivery.configuration.ConfigurationLoaderImpl.load(ConfigurationLoaderImpl.java:48) ~[cd_common_config-8.1.1-1002.jar:8.1.1-1008]
    at com.tridion.dynamiccontent.DynamicContent.loadConfiguration(DynamicContent.java:134) ~[cd_dynamic-8.1.1-1008.jar:8.1.1-1008]
    at com.tridion.dynamiccontent.DynamicContent.<init>(DynamicContent.java:94) ~[cd_dynamic-8.1.1-1008.jar:8.1.1-1008]
    at com.tridion.dynamiccontent.DynamicContent.getInstance(DynamicContent.java:79) ~[cd_dynamic-8.1.1-1008.jar:8.1.1-1008]
    at com.sdl.web.content.datalayer.dynamic.DynamicContentProvider.getPublicationMappingFromUrl(DynamicContentProvider.java:38) ~[content-common-8.1.1-1008.jar:8.1.1-1008]
    at com.sdl.web.content.odata.function.dynamic.GetPublicationMappingsFunction.doContentServiceOperation(GetPublicationMappingsFunction.java:42) ~[content-common-8.1.1-1008.jar:8.1.1-1008]
    at com.sdl.web.content.odata.function.dynamic.GetPublicationMappingsFunction.doContentServiceOperation(GetPublicationMappingsFunction.java:20) ~[content-common-8.1.1-1008.jar:8.1.1-1008]
    at com.sdl.web.content.odata.ContentServiceOperation.doOperation(ContentServiceOperation.java:36) ~[content-common-8.1.1-1008.jar:8.1.1-1008]
    at com.sdl.odata.processor.ODataFunctionProcessorImpl.doFunction(ODataFunctionProcessorImpl.java:63) ~[odata_processor-2.0.5-1002.jar:2.0.5-1002]
    at com.sdl.odata.service.actor.ODataQueryProcessorActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(ODataQueryProcessorActor.scala:36) ~[odata_service-2.0.5-1002.jar:2.0.5-1002]
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:480) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.sdl.odata.service.actor.ODataQueryProcessorActor.aroundReceive(ODataQueryProcessorActor.scala:29) ~[odata_service-2.0.5-1002.jar:2.0.5-1002]
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:526) [akka-actor_2.11-2.4.1.jar:na]
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:495) [akka-actor_2.11-2.4.1.jar:na]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257) [akka-actor_2.11-2.4.1.jar:na]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224) [akka-actor_2.11-2.4.1.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_77]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_77]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_77]
```

Also i have gone through another question [Error on accessing website DXA 1.4](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/14563/error-on-accessing-website-dxa-1-4) where i found that website URL will be mapped with the port number, but what if i have used port 80 with domain name which is default.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a caching issue in your CIS Content Service. I suggest to report this to SDL Customer Support for further analysis and resolution.